# Can't get Jenkins to poll for changes in BitBucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I've installed Jenkins on my local build server and I'm trying to get it to poll bitbucket for changes to my repo and I can't get it to work as I'd like. I'd like to Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket, but I can't get that to work. (I checked "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket". In the mean time I've set it up to poll bitbucket with the settings "H/2 * * * *" which I understand to mean that it should poll every 2 minutes. This appears to be working, but I don't know how to get it to poll only when changes are pushed to bitbucket.

> Started on Feb 10, 2015 8:45:47 AM
>   Using strategy: Default
>   [poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 354dd174247f76e3e78327707a89b0ef370b68ed (refs/remotes/origin/master)
>   using .gitcredentials to set credentials
>   git.exe --version # timeout=10
>   git.exe init C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson8917091258929317136tmp # timeout=10
>   git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Windows\TEMP\git1000935734599110528.credentials\" # timeout=10
>   git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h https://BGoldberg@bitbucket.org/CPA2Biz/souptest.git master # timeout=10
>   git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
>   [poll] Latest remote head revision is: 354dd174247f76e3e78327707a89b0ef370b68ed
>   Done. Took 4.6 sec
>   No changes

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure BitBucket to inform Jenkins when some new code is pushed to BitBucket.

The following link explains how to do this in BitBucket

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Jenkins+hook+management